# Obtaining columns from lists of data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to conduct some data transformation on a dataset with a somewhat messy structure.

Working with a list of data frames and I'm trying to extract the second column from each. In a perfect world, it'd be something straightforward like this.

```
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:2, nrow = 1, ncol = 2))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(9:10, nrow = 1, ncol = 2))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(20:23, nrow=2, ncol =2))

list_a<-list(M1, M2, M3)
output1<-lapply(list_a, "[",,2)
```

But not every dataframe has two columns. Some are missing, as below.

```
M4 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
list_b<-list(M1, M2, M3, M4)
```

Filtering out these problem columns is also pretty straightforward, which then allows me to run the lapply above.

```
filtered<-Filter(function(x) ncol(x)>0, list_b)
```

However, what I really would like to do is preserve those rows with less than two columns as an NA in the output. I've mostly been attempting ifelse statements but they have not been successful.

Comment: Your `M4` is an empty data.frame.  Did you meant that M4 <- data.frame(col1 = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This?

```r
lapply(list_b, function(z) if (ncol(z) > 1) z[,2,drop=FALSE] else NA)
# [[1]]
#   X2
# 1  2
# [[2]]
#   X2
# 1 10
# [[3]]
#   X2
# 1 22
# 2 23
# [[4]]
# [1] NA
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was unfamiliar with the drop argument. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if/else` condition

```
lapply(list_b, \(x) if(ncol(x) < 2) NA else x[[2]])
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 10

[[3]]
[1] 22 23

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

---

`pluck` can still work when there are no columns i.e. by default, it returns `NULL`, we could change it to `NA`

```
library(purrr)
map(list_b, pluck, 2, .default = NA)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 10

[[3]]
[1] 22 23

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Both r2evans and akrun's answers worked.

```
lapply(list_b, function(z) if (ncol(z) > 1) z[,2,drop=FALSE] else NA)
```

Returns a list of data frames, like the original structure.

```
lapply(list_b, \(x) if(ncol(x) < 2) NA else x[[2]])
```

Returns the same values as a simpler list, depending on your preference.
The option below also returns it as a simple list, but does require an additional package.

```
library(purrr)
map(list_b, pluck, 2, .default = NA)
```